# Mount a volume in /var/www/html and the path doesn't find

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I create this docker compose file:

```
 version: '3'

 services: 
   exercise1:
     image: tutum/apache-php
     ports:
        - '80:80'
     volumes:
        - exercise1:/var/www/html
 volumes:
  exercise1:
```

I start with `docker-compose up -d` and after I go in /var/ and www folder doesn't exist? Anyone can help to understand why?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to `/var/www` in your host, right?

That's not correct. The directory `/var/www` in this case is **inside** the container.

The content you are looking for is located in your **host** in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/exercise1/_data`